# finite sub-cover of a class

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathcal{B}$ be a countable open cover of $\mathbb{R}$.

Then how do I show that there exists a finite sub-cover of $\mathcal{B}$ ?

clarification : $\mathcal{B}$ be a class of open subsets  that has countable sets

Reference to [Lemma 1.4.3](http://books.google.com/books?id=GkqQoRpCO2QC&pg=PA23) in Robert Ash; Catherine Dade, "Probability and Measure Theory", Second edition.

The cover set part of the proof makes this assertion.

Comment: Does there exist such a $\mathcal B$? I don't know of a countable open subset in $\mathbb R$ except the empty set.

Comment: Consider $B_n = (-\infty,-n) \cup (n,\infty)$ for $n = -1, 0, 1, \ldots, \infty$

Comment: An open interval is not countable.

Comment: by countable open subset I mean the class $\mathcal{B}$ contains countable number of sets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't deduce this in the general case.

Let $\cal B$ be the collection $\{(-n,n)\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$. Clearly every set is open, and this is a cover of $\Bbb R$. However there is no finite subcover, since a finite collection would only cover a finite interval.

---

In the proof of the lemma the author of the book refers not to a covering of $\Bbb R$, but rather to a compactification of $\Bbb R$, denoted by $\overline{\Bbb R}$ (probably $\Bbb R\cup\{-\infty,+\infty\}$?).

Since $\overline{\Bbb R}$ is a compact set every open cover has a finite subcover. Note that the cover I gave of $\Bbb R$ above does not cover $\overline{\Bbb R}$ because $\pm\infty$ are not covered by such intervals.

Lastly there is nothing to show, as the definition of a compact set is "Every open cover has a finite subcover", so by taking a cover of a compact set we already know that it has a finite subcover.

---

To see that $\overline{\Bbb R}=\Bbb R\cup\{-\infty,+\infty\}$ is compact take $f$ to be any homeomorphism of $\mathbb R$ with $(a,b)$ and extend it in the only reasonable way, $f(-\infty)=a; f(+\infty)=b$. It is now hard to see that this is still a homeomorphism, and $[a,b]$ is compact by the Heine-Borel theorem.

Comment: ok. I came across a related assertion while reading a proof. I tried to formulate this question such that all the properties of the class described in the proof get covered. May be I am missing something.

I will post the reference, Now

Comment: how do I prove that the extended real line is a compact set. If a simple answer is possible please give that, otherwise point me to an easy-to-follow reference.

Comment: If $\overline{\mathbb R} = \mathbb R \cup \{-\infty, +\infty\}$, then it is homeomorphic to $[-1, 1]$ (or any bounded closed interval with non-empty interior).

Comment: @AsafKaragila can you direct me to a reference for this. something of the level of ( http://books.google.co.in/books?id=Q9bmBUnu8XkC )

Comment: @UnadulteratedImagination: I'm not sure what sort of reference you are asking. Do you know that $\mathbb R$ is homeomorphic to $(0,1)$? If so it's not hard to show that you can extend this homeomorphism to $\overline{\mathbb R}$ as defined above. Then the Heine-Borel theorem tells us that $\overline{\mathbb R}$ is compact because $[0,1]$ is a closed-and-bounded interval and therefore compact.